# Использование индекса при поиске по полю типа SET в mySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, индексы

В таблице mySQL InnoDB содержится поле st типа SET, в котором перечисляются страны для каждой записи в таблице. По этому полю построен индекс:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    ...
    `st` SET('Россия','Украина','Беларусия','Узбекистан','Таджикистан','Киргизия','Казахстан',...) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
    INDEX `st` (`st`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

В таблице больше миллиона записей.

Задача создать эффективный (быстрый) поиск-запрос SELECT, использующий индекс по полю типа SET.

Например,выбрать все записи, у которых в поле SET присутствует значение 'Россия' (не равно, а именно присутствует значение).

Вариант с find_in_set()

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Россия',st)
```

не подходит, так как он перебирает все записи таблицы, что накладно с точки зрения производительности.

Можно, конечно хранить полнотекстовый индекс по строковому полю типа TEXT, но это накладно с точки зрения объема данных, так как в реальности стран, присутствующих в поле st намного  больше.

Что посоветуете?

Comment: заменить SET на Много-Ко-Многим

Comment: это разве эффективно по скорости?

Comment: Да, для поиска это очень эффективно. В отдельной таблице поиск будет идти по индексу, по точному соответствию. Разумеется там должно быть не слово "Россия", а некий ID из отдельного справочника. Правда надо понимать, что при поиске по индексу скорость напрямую зависит от количества найденных записей и если по запросу Россия вы выбирете полмиллиона записей, то работать с ними всеми будет явно не быстро

Comment: Функция (в данном случае find_in_set) - это всегда фуллскан. Единственное вменяемое решение - нормализация данных по совету @ArchDemon.